# Eclipse Run Configurations Machine Name

Tags: java, eclipse, windows

I am trying to make a Java Program, but I need the name of the computer I am running this on as an argument.

I know you can get the name with Java code, but that doesn't work on my case. I need it to be provided as an argument in the Run Configurations for Eclipse.

I only need this for Windows computers, so if you have a solution that is Windows-only, that can totally work!

This is how it should look like in the program argument section of the Run Configurations:

```
--username=(GET COMPUTER NAME HERE)
```

I know you can give it variables, such as:

```
${project_loc}
```

Maybe that can help?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: How are you passing other arguments to the application? created any batch/script ?

Comment: I am trying to do a Minecraft Forge mod, so I don't know about other arguments. I am trying to make the Minecraft username (using --username) be equal to the Machine name. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me (SW4STM32 1.14.0):

```
${env_var:COMPUTERNAME}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use

```
${system_property:COMPUTERNAME}
```

to access the computer name in the environment variables.

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't work... Do you have any other suggestions? Thanks a lot!